# Django/Python: How to submit form once div is clicked using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I want a `<form>` from class `up-arrow-form` to be submitted once the `<div>` from class `up-arrow` is clicked. The form contains an `<input>` tag that is `type='hidden'` that has the value `{{i.id}}` that I want passed to the view to be manipulated. How do I do this using Ajax?

***Here is the relavant html from my template...***

```
{% for i in post.posts %}
    <li>
        <div>
             <div class='up-arrow'>
                 <form class='up-arrow-form' action='voteupposts'>
                     <input type='hidden' value='{{i.id}}' name='post-id'>
                 </form>
             </div>
             {{i}}
        </div>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

***Here is my jQuery/AJAX thus far...***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.up-arrow').click(function(){
        $(this).hide()
        $('.up-arrow-form').submit(function(){
            $.get('voteuppost', $(this).serialize(), function(res){
            })
            return false
        })
    });
})
```

***View...***

```
class VoteUpPost(View):
    def get(self, request):
        print(request.GET.get('blaze'))
        return JsonResponse({'status': True})
```

***URL route...***

```
url(r'^voteuppost$', VoteUpPost.as_view()),
```

Comment: There are many problems in your code, you didn't specify the `action` for your `<form>`, and you didn't specify the `name` for your `<input>`. Please read some html basics first: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp.

Comment: `up-arrow-form` is a class: `.up-arrow-form`, not an id: `#up-arrow-form` ;-)

Comment: @AdamJeffers Oh man, its been a long day. Thanks for pointing that out. I just fixed those errors and updated the code. Still not working though. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's an example as to how I would normally use ajax to make a request (incorporating your code). Might not be exactly what you need, but should point you in the right direction...

```
$('.up-arrow').click(function(){
    $(this).hide()
    $('.up-arrow-form').submit(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://someurl.com/voteuppost',
            type: 'GET'
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                // do something on success
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log('err: ' + err);
            }
        });

    });
});
```